# SQL selecting the ID with the name

Tags: sql, oracle

how do i find the ID of a table using the Name?

My Database Schema **BOLD** means PRIMARY KEY , *ITALIC* means FOREIGN KEY

Stages (**stage_id**, took_place, start_loc, end_loc, distance) 
Riders (**rider_id**, name, year_born) 
Results **(stage_id, rider_id,** time_seconds)

Question : If Fred Bradley won the tour. Find the riders who beat him in at least 4 stages, i.e., riders who had a better time than Bradley in at least 4 of the 21 stages. 
I've done as per following. but  i am not sure how to retrieve the rider ID using name.

```
select rider.name
from Results res, Results res2, Riders rider
where rider.name like '%Bradley%' and res.stage_id = res2.stage_id and res.time_seconds > res2.time_seconds
    and res2.rider_id = rider.rider_id 
group by rider.name
having count(*) >= 4
order by name;
```

Comment: add the database you are working on

Comment: Add whether it is oracle or sql server or mysql

Comment: sorry i am using oracle, i've added my database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `rider.name like '%Bradley%` in where clause will return results  of Fred Bradley which is not what the question asks for is

> riders who beat him in at least 4 stages

Try

```
select rider.name
from Results res
join Results res2
on res.stage_id = res2.stage_id and res.time_seconds > res2.time_seconds and res.rider_id = (select r.rider_id from rider r where r.name = 'Fred Bradley')
join  Riders rider
on res2.rider_id = rider.rider_id
group by rider.name
having count(*) >= 4
order by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `id` to the `select` and `group by` lists:

```
SELECT   rider.id, rider.name
FROM     Results res, Results res2, Riders rider
WHERE    rider.name LIKE '%Bradley%' AND 
         res.stage_id = res2.stage_id AND 
         res.time_seconds > res2.time_seconds AND
         res2.rider_id = rider.rider_id 
GROUP BY rider.id, rider.name
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 4
ORDER BY name;
```